# zshell globing works for ls, but not scp

Tags: zsh, scp, globbing

Note: This problem is with **zshell**, it works with bash.

I have some images:

```
$ ls *.jpg
a.jpg b.jpg
```

But when I try to copy them with scp, it says there are none:

```
$ scp *.jpg host:
*.jpg: No such file or directory
```

It works in bash, so this is probably (definitely?) a problem with my zshell config (which uses zprezto). What setting should I look for to fix this sort of thing? Thanks.

Comment: does cp * glob correctly? or is there any alias related to scp in your ~/.zshrc?

Comment: yes `cp *.jpg temp/` works correctly.

Comment: I do not know of any `scp` aliases in my configs.

Comment: Actually, you win. There is an alias buried in one of the includes. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any aliases related to the scp command in your ~/.zshrc?

If so, remove those aliases.